# Javascript if scroll position > 100

Tags: javascript, scroll, alert, scrolltop

How can I test it if it's greater than 100. For example how can I get an alert.

Here is my code that doesn't work, I don't know why.

```
var ScrollTop = $("body").scrollTop();

if (ScrollTop > 100){
    alert("Scroll is greater than 100");
    //document.getElementById('back-to-top').fadeOut;
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it worked for me. I think some debugging is in order for you.

Comment: do you have this code in a spot that continuously checks the scroll positions, like in an onscroll event?

Comment: where should I put this code in? in head? or after body? or does it work in both? I couln't make it happen lol

Comment: I just put it in <script> tag.

Comment: @Alpan Karaca:please accept the answer you think is worthy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a scroll listener http://jsfiddle.net/6A6qy/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){...});
```

Comment: Thank you verbanicm it worked with the listener. I didn't know that, I'm new at javascript.

Answer (score 2):

[PERFECT FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TLkmK/8/)

```
var el = $('.test');

el.on('scroll', function(){

  alert(el.scrollTop());


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to take $(document).scrollTop() instead of $('body)